# Evaluate if both statements are false

Tags: java

I have a ruby background and new to java. Its a little bit confusing for me and i have a very simple exercise that i couldnt save.

My method looks like this:

```
public void act() 
    {
        while((treeLeft() == false) && (treeRight() == false))
        {
            move();
        }
    }
}
```

So normally my code should check if there is a tree on both sides ( treeleft == true and treeright == true) and when there are really trees on both sides stop and not move.

But somehow it doesnt move although there is only a tree on the left side? What do i wrong?

Comment: That should work the same in Java as it does in Ruby. Do you mean `false` or `true`? As your code is, if `treeLeft()` and `treeRight()` both return `false` then it calls `move()`; otherwise it doesn't. Is that what you intend?

Comment: Whats wrong with `if(!treeLeft() && !treeRight()) {`

Comment: Does treeLeft() and treeRight() return a boolean or Boolean?  To make things a little easier try `(treeLeft() && treeRight())`  No need to to check the value of a boolean.

Comment: Hope you got your answer, just to add, in java and as per java guidelines, boolean should not be compared with ==. It should be used as if(booleanField) not like if(booleanField == true) as you can see in answers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the `&&` operator works, is by first evaluating the left side, and if that evaluates to `false` it doesn't bother with evaluting the right side, since the result of the expression as a whole will be `false` no matter the outcome of the right side. So, once treeLeft() evaluates to true, the `while` is broken and moves stop.

The correct way to do this would be:

```
while(!(treeLeft() && treeRight()))
```

Which means that the `while` will keep looping until both treeLeft() and treeRight() evaluates to true.

Alternative version, using DeMorgan's law:

```
while(!treeLeft() || !treeRight())
```

Comment: I don't think the short-circuiting behavior of `&&` is relevant. DeMorgan's law, that's where the money's at.

Comment: The `&&` is not that important, but it explains the behaviour he sees, where the left side alone breaks the `while`. Also, it is nice to know for new java developers :)

Comment: Right, DeMorgan's Law applies both to short-circuiting and non-short-circuiting operators.  It also applies to bitwise operators: `~(a & b)` equals `(~a) | (~b)`, and `~(a | b)` equals `(~a) & (~b)`.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` operator evaluates to `false` anytime EITHER value is `false`.

`||` operator evaluates to `false` only when BOTH values are `false`, and is probably what you need to use in this situation.

```
while(!treeLeft() || !treeRight()) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

For clarity (I'm not familiar with Ruby)... `!treeLeft()` is exactly the same as `treeLeft() == false`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the || (or) operator. for this to click both statements need to be true. As it stands if the first statement is true you will end the loop.

If you are trying to short circuit to put a preference on the left tree then keep it first in the while loop condition. It is important to remember that these are evaluated in order. Short circuiting can be very useful. Look at the this if you want an explanation: https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs132/Weekly/W02/SCBooleans.html

Also may give you some hints on how you should restructure

Answer (score 0):

In your code move() will only be called if both treeLeft() and treeRight() return false. This means it won´t be called as long as you have a tree on the left OR the right side. So what you want is propably:

```
while(!(treeLeft() && treeRight()))
```